# Turn level of MultiIndex columns into a column with values (unstack columns)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DraFrame with a MultiIndex in the columns, and I want to turn the first level into its own column.

Original df

```py
pd.DataFrame(
    {
        ('a', 'm1'): [0,1],
        ('a', 'm2'): [10, 11],
        ('b', 'm1'): [2,3],
        ('b', 'm2'): [12, 13],
        ('c', 'm1'): [3,4],
        ('c', 'm2'): [13,14],
    },
)

#    a      b      c
#   m1  m2 m1  m2 m1  m2
# 0  0  10  2  12  3  13
# 1  1  11  3  13  4  14
```

Desired dataframe:

```
 m1 m2 level0
 0  10 a
 1  11 a
 2  12 b
 3  13 b
 3  13 c
 4  14 c
```

I tried using [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), but I couldn't get the desired effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little fun:

```
df.stack().T.stack(0)
```

Output:

```
     m1  m2
a 0   0  10
  1   1  11
b 0   2  12
  1   3  13
c 0   3  13
  1   4  14
```

Closer to your desired output:

```
df.stack().T.stack(0).reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  level_0  m1  m2
0       a   0  10
1       a   1  11
2       b   2  12
3       b   3  13
4       c   3  13
5       c   4  14
```

Comment: Using `df.stack().T.stack(0).reset_index(level=0)` works great, because I can keep the original index.